# Is "thunderhead" a living English word?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I was taught a word *thunderhead* means "cumulonimbus" in American English. However, Several speakers said they didn't use the word when [I asked it on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27551775#27551775). It seems that the word certainly [appears in corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=45127793).

Do you use, or know this word? Do you know where, or by what kind of people it's used? Am I correct with its meaning?

Comment: Were they Americans and did they live in the **Midwest**? That's where the real **thunderheads** occur.  Oklahoma's basketball team is called **The Thunder**.  nGram [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thunderhead&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthunderhead%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Peter Thank you. Could you perhaps elaborate it into an answer? I'm especially curious about what is the "real thunderheads".

Comment: **real** is a qualifier and I'm using it to mean big and massive. So if you get to experience a thunderstorm in the Midwest where the thunder rattles the windows and the house shakes and you go momentarily deaf because it's so loud. Then compared to that, any other thunderstorm will not seem so **real**.  It's like: Coca-Cola - It;s the **real thing** *(meaning not Pepsi)*.  But were the people you were chatting with from the Midwest? Not everywhere will have thunderstorms like those.

Comment: @Peter So, do they call the massive thunderclouds typically seen in the Midwest as "thunderheads"? I think no one I talked with was from the Midwest.

Comment: I don't think *thunderhead* is a term belonging to a certain region or demographic per se, it's just a moderately uncommon word. I would expect its usage to be most frequent in areas with large, frequent thunderstorms, such as the American Midwest as @Peter suggested. More common synonyms for *thunderhead* include *storm cloud* and *thunder cloud*.

Comment: Yes, those are cumulonimbus, when there is a thunderstorm, then they become **thunderheads** which can also take the form of  [**anvil clouds**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulonimbus_incus).  The clouds form a large column of up and down drafts, planes will fly around these clouds to avoid the turbulence. The up drafts are what can create **hail** and produce a layered effect by constant freezing. Pics of thunderheads [here](http://www.mymodernmet.com/profiles/blogs/ominous-thunderhead-clouds)

Comment: Yes exactly @Peter, Thunderhead for me means one of those monster anvil clouds. Grew up on the edge of 'tornado alley' and yeah, you see a couple of those and you start wondering where your shelter is for the next half hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*cumulonimbus* is generally used in a technical discussion of the weather. We learned it in school in science lessons, but nowadays ???
I don't think many people would point up at a cloud and call it *cumulonimbus*.

"thundercloud" could be used if you are on the ground pointing at it, but I think it is more likely one would use "thunderstorm":

> There is a **thunderstorm** coming.
>   Than looks like a really bad **thunderstorm**.

As for *thunderhead*, I would use this if I were on the ground and could see the cloud all the way to the top, or if I were in an airplane flying (at high altitude) near one.

(AmE disclaimer)

Comment: I am willing to bet that more Americans can draw a "thunderhead" than know what "cumulonimbus" means.

Comment: @Jasper Maybe they don't teach science in school anymore...